# How exactly do runtime environments work?

Tags: javascript, .net, frameworks, runtime

I'm having some trouble understanding this whole thing. I get that a runtime environment is essentially a virtual machine which sits on top of the operating system and allows applications to be run completely cross-platform, but I just don't get *how* it can do that. Aren't different operating systems made differently? How can one runtime environment run on all operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, there's a lot more going on behind the scenes, that you don't ever hear about. Runtime environments are built in multiple levels, each one getting closer and closer to what you see as a developer.
They go through first, and rewrite the lowest level connectors for each operating system, to point to the different spots on the machine. Then, as they move up the levels, it gets closer and closer to being identical, until you have the full runtime environment, which appears (almost) identical on every type of computer. I say almost because the translation isn't always perfect. You'll see this if you run programs that have a GUI built in Java. Java uses the platform default buttons, so on a Mac, they are Mac style buttons, and on Windows, Windows style buttons, even though it is the exact same program.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I guess it's best to see it as layers of abstraction.

Comment: Exactly, the runtime environment is abstracted to the level that the programmer doesn't have to care about the intricacies of each operating system. If this answered your question, would you mind accepting it?